# Reverse a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program for school. I'm a biotech major and this is a required course, but I'm not a programmer. So, this is probably easy for many, but difficult for me. Anyway, I have a text file with about 30 lines. Each line has a movie name listed first and actors who appeared in the movie, separated by commas following. Here's what I have so far:

```
InputName = input('What is the name of the file? ')
File = open(InputName, 'r+').readlines()


ActorLst = []
for line in File:
    MovieActLst = line.split(',')   


    Movie = MovieActLst[0]        
    Actors = MovieActLst[1:]      
    for actor in Actors:
        if actor not in ActorLst:
            ActorLst.append(actor)

    MovieDict = {Movie: Actors for x in MovieActLst} 
    print (MovieDict)
    print(len(MovieDict))
```

Output(shortened):

```
What is the name of the file? Movies.txt
{"Ocean's Eleven": ['George Clooney', 'Brad Pitt', 'Elliot Gould', 'Casey Affleck', 'Carl Reiner', 'Julia Roberts', 'Angie Dickinson', 'Steve Lawrence', 'Wayne Newton\n']}
1
{'Up in the Air': ['George Clooney', 'Sam Elliott', 'Jason Bateman\n']}
1
{'Iron Man': ['Robert Downey Jr', 'Jeff Bridges', 'Gwyneth Paltrow\n']}
1
{'The Big Lebowski': ['Jeff Bridges', 'John Goodman', 'Julianne Moore', 'Sam Elliott\n']}
1
```

I have created a dictionary (`MovieDict`) that contains a movie name for the key and a list of actors for the values. There are about 30 movie names (keys). I need to figure out how to iterate through this dictionary to essentially reverse it. I want a dictionary that contains an actor as a key and the movies they play in as the values.

However, I think I have created a list of dictionaries as well instead of one dictionary and now I have really confused myself! Any suggestions?

Comment: Before you hand it in, you might want to do something about those newline characters. After all, who is "Gwyneth Paltrow\n"? Try `MovieActLst = line.strip().split(',')`.

Comment: I don't understand how you could possibly get by as a biotech major without knowing any programming.

Comment: Well, Joel, that is why I'm taking the class. My point, is that I have not played around with computer programming like most computer science majors have. This is all new to me. I just aced my exam. I know the material for the most part; I just have a hard time putting it into the actual programs I have to write. And, to Junuxx, I did take care of those newline characters just a few minutes ago- right before you posted your response.

Comment: I was looking at your question and getting _really_ confused by the syntax highlighting. You've camel cased every variable, which in a standard notation means it's a class.

Answer (score 5):

Trivial using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
reverse = defaultdict(list)

for movie, actors in MovieDict.items():
    for actor in actors:
        reverse[actor].append(movie)
```

The`defaultdict` class differs from `dict` because when you try to access a key that does not exist, it creates it and sets its value to an item created by the factory passed to the constructor(`list` in the above code), this avoids catching the `KeyError` or checking if the key is in the dictionary.

Putting this with Steven Rumbalski's loop results in:

```
from collections import defaultdict
in_fname = input('What is the name of the file? ')
in_file = open(in_fname, 'r+')

movie_to_actors = {}
actors_to_movie = defaultdict(list)

for line in in_file:
    #assumes python3:
    movie, *actors = line.strip().split(',')
    #python2 you can do actors=line.strip().split(',');movie=actors.pop(0)

    movie_to_actors[movie] = list(actors)
    for actor in actors:
        actors_to_movie[actor].append(movie)
```

---

Some explanations about the code above.

### Iterating over the lines of a file

File object are iterable, and thus support iteration.
This means you can do:

```
for line in open('filename'):
```

instead of:

```
for line in open('filename').readlines():
```

(Also in python2 the latter reads all file and then splits the content, while iterating over the file does not read all file into memory[and so you may save a lot of RAM with big files]).

### Tuple unpacking

To "unpack" a sequence into different variables you can use the "tuple unpacking" syntax:

```
>>> a,b = (0,1)
>>> a
0
>>> b
1
```

The syntax was extended to allow gathering of a variable number of values into a variable.
For example:

```
>>> head, *tail = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> head
1
>>> tail
[2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> first, *mid, last = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> first
0
>>> mid
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> last
5
```

You can have only one "starred expression", so this does not work:

```
>>> first, *mid, center, *mid2, last  =(0,1,2,3,4,5)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: two starred expressions in assignment
```

So basically when you have a star on the left hand side, python puts there everything that it wasn't able to put in other variables. Notice that this mean that the variable may refer to an empty list:

```
>>> first, *mid, last = (0,1)
>>> first
0
>>> mid
[]
>>> last
1
```

### Using defaultdict

The `defaultdict` allows you to give a default value to non existent keys.
The class accepts a callable(~function or class) as parameter and calls it to build a default value everytime that it's required:

```
>>> def factory():
...     print("Called!")
...     return None
... 
>>> mydict = defaultdict(factory)
>>> mydict['test']
Called!
```

Comment: I purposely left `defaultdict` out so as to avoid overwhelming the OP (the with-statement, advanced tuple unpacking, and treating and open file as an iterator where quite much already).  However, I agree that `defaultdict` is the best approach here.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I've updated my answer with some explanations. Hope this helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
reverse={}
keys=MovieDict.keys()
for key in keys:
    val=MovieDict[key]
    for actor in val:
        try:
            reverse[actor]=reverse[actor].append(actor)
        except KeyError:
            reverse[actor]=[]
            reverse[actor]=reverse[actor].append(actor)
print(reverse)#retarded python 3 format! :)
```

That should do it.

Comment: When I try to apply the above code, I'm getting a syntax error for except KeyError:

Comment: Of course there is no `try` clause..
Use `import collections; reverse=collections.defaultdict(list)` instead of catching the `KeyError`.

Comment: Also you can simply iterate over MovieDict instead of MovieDict.keys()

Comment: damm hung over error. "I shall not use stackoverflow when I am drunk".

Answer (score 1):

```
InputName = input('What is the name of the file? ')
with open(InputName, 'r') as f:
    actors_by_movie = {}
    movies_by_actor = {}
    for line in f:
        movie, *actors = line.strip().split(',')
        actors_by_movie[movie] = actors
        for actor in actors:
            movies_by_actor.setdefault(actor, []).append(movie)
```

Comment: @thg435:  You are correct.  It should be `setdefault`.  The error stems from my decision not to use a `defaultdict` for fear of introducing too many concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Programming is about abstracting things, so try to write code in a way that doesn't depend on the specific problem. For example:

```
def csv_to_dict(seq, separator=','):
    dct = {}
    for item in seq:
        data = [x.strip() for x in item.split(separator)]
        if len(data) > 1:
            dct[data[0]] = data[1:]
    return dct

def flip_dict(dct):
    rev = {}
    for key, vals in dct.items():
        for val in vals:
            if val not in rev:
                rev[val] = []
            rev[val].append(key)
    return rev
```

Note how these two functions don't "know" anything about "input files", "actors", "movies" and so on, but still are able to solve your problem with two lines of code:

```
with open("movies.txt") as fp:
    print(flip_dict(csv_to_dict(fp)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your naming conventions:

```
from collections import defaultdict

InputName = input('What is the name of the file? ')
File = open(InputName, 'rt').readlines()

ActorLst = []
ActMovieDct = defaultdict(list)
for line in File:
    MovieActLst = line.strip().split(',')
    Movie = MovieActLst[0]
    Actors = MovieActLst[1:]
    for actor in Actors:
        ActMovieDct[actor].append(Movie)

# print results    
for actor, movies in ActMovieDct.items():
    print(actor, movies)
```